# Entity Framework causes primary key constraint on target table while adding n to n relation

Tags: entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have a n to n relation between groups and accessgroups. When adding the first record, if all works fine, in the accessgroupGroups table a record is created, but when updating the set with an additional link I get an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AccessGroups'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'AccessGroups'. The duplicate key value is (66822d47-b020-481e-9c61-148457ffb1e6)

and indeed that key is already present in the `AccessGroups` table because this action should have made an additional record in the `AccessgroupGroups` table

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class AccessGroup
{
    public AccessGroup()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Users = new List<User>();
        Groups = new List<Group>();
     }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AccessGroup Parent { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        AccessGroups = new List<AccessGroup>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<AccessGroup> AccessGroups { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        ToTable("Groups");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

          HasOptional(x => x.AccessGroups).WithMany().Map( m=>m.ToTable("AccessGroupGroups"));
    }
}

public class AccessGroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AccessGroup>
{
    public AccessGroupMap()
    {
        ToTable("AccessGroups");
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(MappingConstants.NameLength);

        HasOptional(t => t.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.ParentId);

        HasMany(t => t.Groups)
            .WithMany(t => t.AccessGroups)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("AccessGroupGroups");
                m.MapLeftKey("AccessgroupId");
                m.MapRightKey("GroupId");
            });
    }
}

public void SaveGroupAccessGroups(Model.DB.Group group)
{
    var existing = db.Groups.Include(x => x.AccessGroups).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == group.Id);

    if (existing is not null)
    {
         var old = existing.AccessGroups.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
         existing.AccessGroups.AddRange(group.AccessGroups.Where(y => !existing.AccessGroups.Select(q => q.Id).Contains(y.Id)));
         existing.AccessGroups.RemoveAll(x => !group.AccessGroups.Any( y => y.Id == x.Id));

         foreach (var q in existing.AccessGroups)
         {
             db.Entry(q).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
         }

         db.Commit();
    }
}
```

Both the groups and the accessGroups have already multiple record and now I expected to add/ update/ remove record in the AccessGroupGroups table.

These are the majority of the code causing the problems. I guess there should be something additionally in the map classed, but I have no idea on what. Hopefully somebody here has the answer.

I have also tried to replace all the items in the existing object:

```
existing.AccessGroups.Clear()
existing.AccessGroups.AddRange(group.AccessGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the link to the Parent Accessgroup was the problem, closer examination of the error showed me the the problem was that EF was trying to add the Parent of the linked accessgroup into the Accessgroup table, even though it was there already, obviously. so marking the database state for an optional parent for any of the added accessgroups as `db.Entry(q.Parent).State = EntityState.Unchanged` solved the problem partly, especially when multi nested. I ended up with setting the Parent item to null prior to storing the data.

even though this solution kind of worked, I wasn't happy with it and looking further gave me the I guess the correct solution

the problem is that since the data is traveling through the application and thus transformed to a List<> the actual link between the list and the actual data in the database is lost, causing Entity Framework to get confused and trying to add the record again.

my final solution looks like this

```
public void SaveGroupAccessGroups(Model.DB.Group group)
{
    var existing = db.Groups.Include(x => x.AccessGroups).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == group.Id);
    if (existing is not null)
    {
        existing.AccessGroups.Clear();
        foreach (var item in group.AccessGroups)
        {
            var accessGroup = db.AccessGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id && x.DateTimeDeleted == null);
            if (accessGroup != null && !existing.AccessGroups.Contains(item))
            {
                existing.AccessGroups.Add(accessGroup);
            }
        }
        db.Commit();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help others to find the solution for similar problems